# Swagger: Endpoints are not initialised

Tags: java, jersey, swagger

When configuring swagger for javax endpoint, I am getting the below warning. Can you explain what I am missing?

I have attached the code I am using for initialising swagger and to attached to the server.

Waring in the log:

```
Attempting to start Grizzly on http://0.0.0.0:52204
Feb 26, 2018 3:09:55 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider ipos.hashgraph.utils.Swagger registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider ipos.hashgraph.utils.Swagger will be ignored. 
Feb 26, 2018 3:09:56 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [0.0.0.0:52204]
```

Code used:

```
public class Swagger extends ResourceConfig {

        public Swagger(){
            register(DocumentApi.class);
            register(JacksonFeature.class);

            register(ApiListingResource.class);
            property(MessageProperties.XML_FORMAT_OUTPUT, true);
            property(ServerProperties.TRACING, "ALL");
        }


        public void initializeSwaggerConfiguration() {

            final ReflectiveJaxrsScanner scanner = new ReflectiveJaxrsScanner();
            scanner.setResourcePackage("ipos.hashgraph.rest");
            ScannerFactory.setScanner(scanner);
            ClassReaders.setReader(new DefaultJaxrsApiReader());
            final SwaggerConfig config = ConfigFactory.config();
           // config.setApiVersion("1.0");
            config.setBasePath("http://localhost:8080/swagger/");
        }
}
```

Server initialisation

```
public static void initREST(int port, String[] packages) {
        URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://0.0.0.0").port(port).build();
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig()
                .register(new CORSFilter())
                .register(new Swagger())
                .register(JacksonFeature.class);

        for (String pkg : packages) {
            config.packages(pkg);
        }

        System.out.println("Attempting to start Grizzly on " + baseUri);
        GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, config);

        try {
            platform.createTransaction(
                    new ExoMessage(
                            new 
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```